# Issues with VScode: Cannot open, code.exe file missing, and failed download

Tags: installation, browser, download, missing-data, failed-installation

I have been having some issues with my VScode. I am unable to open it and instead, I see a message that the code.exe file has been moved or deleted. I have tried reinstalling VScode from the official website, but the download fails after reaching 100%. I have also tried downloading it on my phone and transferring it to my laptop, but the file disappears after a few seconds.

Can you please help me with this issue? Thank you.

I have tried to reinstall VSCode from the official website, but it failed to download and showed a 'couldn't download' message after reaching 100%. I also attempted to download the file on my phone and transfer it to my laptop, but the file disappeared a few seconds later. I expected to successfully reinstall VSCode and be able to use it without any issues.

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact same problem today.

My VSCode code.exe did move to: C:\Users<User>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code_

There is a new folder with the name "_".

Comment: Same problem. To solve, put the contents of the "_" folder to the path `C:\Users<User>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code`